# Кроссбраузерное воспроизведение аудио

Tags: html, javascript

Необходимо воспроизвести звук на странице.

Comment: онли флеш, либо тег audio (соответственно нужно поддержка html5, http://htmlbook.ru/html/audio)

Comment: А во ВК как работает?

Comment: Точнее через что?

Comment: @exec по моему через флеш, но мб скорее всего также реализована поддержка через тег.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[audio.js — слушаем музыку в любом браузере](http://habrahabr.ru/post/110906/)

Answer (score 0):

В свое время тоже сталкивался с этой проблемой. Не хотелось через flash реализовывать, но уж больно не понравилось, что разные браузеры разные форматы поддерживают.
Если не ошибаюсь, то Firefox поддерживает чуть ли не только OGG. Тогда как Хром может воспроизводить MP3.

Пришлось остановится всё-таки на flash. Благо не обязательно тут писать всё самому, существуют уже хорошие и легкие плейеры. Например, в свое время помог сайт:

[плейеры](http://yapro.ru/web-master/flashmx/obzor-flash-audio-pleerov.html)

Контакт действительно работает с помощью флеша, если мы говорим о воспроизведении видео и аудио, но для iOS есть поддержка HTML5, благо у Safari вроде всё нормально с поддержкой популярных форматов

Желаю удачи!